# Tabs/Swipe view in fragment loaded in main activity using navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, tabs, fragment

I'm using a navigation drawer and loading fragments in every time a menu item is selected.  But I have one fragment that I want to use tabs/swipe views on so this fragment will itself have multiple fragments I'm switching in between.

My question is what's the best way to implement the swipe view/tabs inside a fragment that's loaded in the main activity.  Any good tutorials on this?  Should I add tabs to the action bar in the main activity or is there a better way to do this?

Any code snippet examples I see online or from the android developer site causes my app to crash and I have a tough time debugging the problem.

Any examples or ideas?

Thanks.

---

Here's some code I started but how can I change things like style the tabs and alter background color, underline tab color, font, etc.  I haven't actually added fragment layouts/data to the tabs but I have a dummy fragment I load that's empty for now.  So I can begin changing the fragments I'm loading into the tabs easy by just doing standard XML layout stuff, but what about customizing the tabs themselves and their appearance?

I used the adapter I did because I don't want to destroy anything, I need access to all the information across tabs since it'll be a step 1 to step X sort of thing, will that be a memory issue?  There's only like 5-8, not hundreds of tabs.

THANKS.

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragment) {
    super(fragment);
}

 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int i) 
 {
     //testing, remove later
     Fragment fragment = new DummyFragment();
     return fragment;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
     return 6;  //6 tabs
 }

 @Override
 public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
     return "OBJECT " + (position + 1); //dummy title
 }
}

public class TabFragment extends Fragment  {

private FragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

//@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{               
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs, container, false);

    //this will be our swipe/tab view populated with each checkout
    //piece fragment
    mPagerAdapter =
            new PagerAdapter(
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    return view;
}   
}

public class DummyFragment extends Fragment {

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dummy, container, false);
     return view;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My app uses this same pattern, you will need to set your minimum API level to 17 and use getChildFragmentManager. So basically the Fragment you load when you click on a nav drawer item will host a bunch of child fragments inside of it. I found it useful to make the child fragments static inner classes for this.

Your Fragment you load inside the activity should have an XML layout like this

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pagerTitleStrip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"/>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

So you inflate this as the parent fragments layout, and set an adapter with a bunch of child fragments.

Comment: Thanks, I added it and made my fragment inflate the view so I have a good start now.  Do you have an example using FragmentPagerAdapter in my context I described?  The android docs don't relate to what I explained since I'm not in the main activity I'm in a fragment.

Comment: Yeah, i have tons of examples. Im in class, ill post in a few hours.

Comment: Ok thanks, let me post you something I just started using the direction you gave me and tell me what you think or if I can do better.  It's not a 100% implemented solution but I think I got it working as I'd hope but I still want to customize.